# Make and apt-get Have Stopped Working

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, make, dependencies

So I downloaded the non-free broadcom driver(b44) for my debian install, however when I try to make it I get the following error:

```
make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/scroty/workplace/b44-1.00g modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

So I looked up my errors, and some other guy [here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/8463/solved-make-having-trouble-finding-libmoduleskernelbuild/) had the same thing, and he fixed it by installing the kernel headers. So I try to do the same, and this is what happens:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64 : Depends: gcc-4.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

When I try to install gcc-4.3 it's the same thing, except with several more dependencies(some of which I know I have). When I run:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep gcc
```

it returns:

```
gcc
gcc-4.3-base
gcc-4.4-base
gcc-4.7
gcc-4.7-base
libgcc1
```

So is it bad that I have several different versions of the same package? Is there any reason I shouldn't just delete gcc-4.3 and gcc-4.4 since I have 4.7? I'm having a bit of trouble completely understanding the whole package system.

**EDIT:** Does the '32' in 'linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64' mean that it's meant for 32bit machiens? Because I'm running 64bit, however I figured 32bit apps would still run.

Comment: The .32 is just part of the version number, it doesn't have anything to do with 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the info. Do you have any idea what might be going on here? Apt-get just doesn't want to work anymore. Doesn't apt-get automatically find and include dependencies?

Comment: Try running `apt-get update`, then try the original `apt-get install` command again.  Dependencies should be installed automatically, if they're not that suggests that your package lists might be out of date.

Comment: What version of debian are you running?

Comment: I'm running squeeze. I've run update a bunch, it still won't work. I've also run apt-get -f install. By package list do you mean sources? I can post it if that will help.

Comment: By package lists, I meant the ones that get updated by running `apt-get update`, too large to post and unlikely to be helpful.  The list of sources might be informative if there's anything unusual in them.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know if it's bad that I have several different versions of the same package? Is there any reason I shouldn't just delete gcc-4.3-base and gcc-4.4-base since I have 4.7? I'm having a bit of trouble completely understanding the whole package system.

Comment: You don't have several versions of packages, dpkg doesn't allow that.  The version numbers there are part of the package name.  That's done specifically so that those packages can be installed at the same time, so it shouldn't be a problem.  That kernel-headers package explicitly depends on the gcc-4.3 packages, so it wouldn't be satisfied by gcc-4.7.

Comment: Actually, you could have several versions of gcc installed, but only one would be configured as the default compiler. see [debian alternatives](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) for some explanations. I am not sure if this would have an effect in your situation though.